# Splitting an edge into two parts in a probabilistic automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

I am currently trying to split an edge in an automaton in tikz. What I already have is this: [image]

I would like to get somethink like this (not in red, just to highlight): [image]
The idea is to have a probabilistic automaton. If the automaton gets the input D, it changes with probability 2/3 to state q1 and with probability 1/3 it remains in state q3. That it why I would like to have one outgoing edge from q3 with input D, the edge should split after a while as you can see in the picture. How can I achieve that?

Here is my code (I needed some if the other tikzlibraries for other parts of my original code, so don't get confused):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip=half+]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart} % Import library for 
     drawing automata
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees} %For graphics
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % ...positioning nodes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes} % ...customizing arrows
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{node distance=2.5cm, %Minimum distance between nodes
   every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, fill=gray!10, circle split, 
   align=center}, %properties for each state
   initial text={}, %No label on start state
   final/.style=accepting,
   every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
   brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[{node distance=1.5cm, ,shorten >=1pt,%Minimum 
      distance between nodes
      every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=1pt, 
      fill=gray!10, circle, align=center}, %properties for each state
      initial text={}, %No label on start arrow
      final/.style=accepting,
      every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
      brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick,
      every loop/.style={min distance=5mm,looseness=5}}]
   \node[state,initial] (q1) {$q_i^1$ \\ -------- \\ A}; 
   \node[state] (q2) [right=of q1] {$q_i^2$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \node[state] (q3) [right=of q2] {$q_i^3$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \draw[->] (q1) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q1);
   \draw[->] (q1) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q2);
   \draw[->] (q2) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q3);
   \draw[->] (q3) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q3); 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, I just realised that the state I meant was named q2 in the picture. I'm sorry for that. I mean the state named q3 in the code if it was not clear (I changed it in the code). I am thankful for any help I get. You can also find nice examples of what I would like to get in [this](http://wwwhome.ewi.utwente.nl/~marielle/papers/pa.pdf) articles (page 4, figures 2 and 3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is rather easy to do that with `decorations.markings`. Below the same thing is achieved by a style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip=half+]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart} % Import library for drawing automata
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees} %For graphics
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % ...positioning nodes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes} % ...customizing arrows
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{node distance=2.5cm, %Minimum distance between nodes
   every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, fill=gray!10, circle split, 
   align=center}, %properties for each state
   initial text={}, %No label on start state
   final/.style=accepting,
   every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
   brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[{node distance=1.5cm, ,shorten >=1pt,%Minimum 
      distance between nodes
      every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=1pt, 
      fill=gray!10, circle, align=center}, %properties for each state
      initial text={}, %No label on start arrow
      final/.style=accepting,
      every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
      brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick,
      every loop/.style={min distance=5mm,looseness=5}}]
   \node[state,initial] (q1) {$q_i^1$ \\ -------- \\ A}; 
   \node[state] (q2) [right=of q1] {$q_i^2$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \node[state] (q3) [right=of q2] {$q_i^3$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \draw[->] (q1) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q1);
   \draw[->] (q1) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q2);
   \draw[->] (q2) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q3);
   \draw[->] (q3) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q3); 
   \draw[->,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
   mark=at position 0.25 with {\draw[->] (0pt,0pt) to[bend left] 
   coordinate[midway](aux) (q3);
   \pgftransformreset
   \node[above=2pt of aux]{$1/3$};}}}] (q3) to[out=135,in=45] 
   node[midway,above]{$2/3$}  (q1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the same thing with a style

```
split connection=at <pos of splitting point> with ratio <label> to <additional target>
```

and an example in the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip=half+]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart} % Import library for drawing automata
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees} %For graphics
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % ...positioning nodes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes} % ...customizing arrows
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{node distance=2.5cm, %Minimum distance between nodes
   every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, fill=gray!10, circle split, 
   align=center}, %properties for each state
   initial text={}, %No label on start state
   final/.style=accepting,
   every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
   brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, shorten >=1pt,%Minimum 
      distance between nodes
      every state/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=1pt, 
      fill=gray!10, circle, align=center}, %properties for each state
      initial text={}, %No label on start arrow
      final/.style=accepting,
      every picture/.style={>=stealth'},
      brace/.style={decorate,decoration=brace}, semithick,
      every loop/.style={min distance=5mm,looseness=5},
      split connection/.style args={at #1 with ratio #2 to #3}{postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
   mark=at position #1 with {\draw[->] (0pt,0pt) to[bend left] 
   coordinate[midway](aux) (#3);
   \pgftransformreset
   \node[above=2pt of aux]{$#2$};}}}}
   ]
   \node[state,initial] (q1) {$q_i^1$ \\ -------- \\ A}; 
   \node[state] (q2) [right=of q1] {$q_i^2$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \node[state] (q3) [right=of q2] {$q_i^3$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
   \draw[->] (q1) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q1);
   \draw[->] (q1) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q2);
   \draw[->] (q2) edge node [above] {\texttt{D}} (q3);
   \draw[->] (q3) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q3); 
   \draw[->,split connection=at 0.25 with ratio $1/3$ to q3] (q3) to[out=135,in=45] 
   node[midway,above]{$2/3$}   node[midway,below]{\texttt{D}} (q1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks nice! Thank you so much. Do you also know how to add the label "D" at that part of the edge where there was still only one edge (the lower part of the edge)?

Comment: @Unicorn Sure, just replace `node[midway,below]{\texttt{D}}` by `node[pos=0.125,below]{\texttt{D}}`. One could also make this part of the style, but the style would then become a bit bulky because it would have tons of parameters. If you tell me which version (style or no style) you like better, I could clean up.

Comment: I first implemented the no style version, but now I'm using the style version. Works perfectly fine, no need to spend more time. They both saved my day. Perhaps another question, it is not of great importance, but so that I understand the tikz automata stuff better (I am following the approach of "learning" by doing or, to my shame, letting other people do it.)
It may look better if the self-pointing edge in state q3 bends from right to left and not from left to right. It should still loop over the state, not under it. How can this be achieved? (i.e. as in q1, but mirrored vertically)

Comment: @Unicorn That's very simple. Just add a style `my loop above/.style={out=75,in=105,loop},` e.g. to the options of the tikzpicture or add `\tikzset{my loop above/.style={out=75,in=105,loop}}`, and then use `my loop above` instead of `loop above`. (That's a strange site on which a unicorn talks to a marmot. ;-)

Comment: Well, you know, anything is possible on the Internet.  
Perfect, exactly what I was hoping for (took the style). Once you know how to do it, everything is simple. But if you have no idea, the solution is farther away than the universe. Maybe I should really start learning it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

An option using `..controls +(direction:module) and +(direction:module)..` line because nodes in a path `node[pos=0_to_1_value]` does not work for bend <s>or to[in.., out]</s>, using nodes in a path allows to put a node in ceirtain positions in this case at 0.12 for the D label using `node[pos=0.12,below]...` for the 2/3 label `node[pos=0.8]...` and to split the arrow an empty node `node[pos=0.25](temp){}`, temp is the node_name, and then drawing an arrow from temp.center to (q3) usign controls again to put a node in a path with the label 1/3...

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart} % Import library for drawing automata
\usetikzlibrary{calc, trees} %For graphics
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % ...positioning nodes
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes} % ...customizing arrows
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
%Fonts MAnagement
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % For Sans Family
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Config
        node distance=1.5cm,
        shorten >=1pt,%Minimum distance between nodes
        semithick,
        font=\sffamily,
        >={Stealth},
        %Environment Styles
        every state/.style={
            minimum size=0pt,
            inner sep=1pt,
            fill=gray!10,
            circle,
            align=center
        }, %properties for each state
        initial text={}, %No label on start arrow
        final/.style={accepting},
        brace/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration=brace
        }, 
        every loop/.style={
            min distance=5mm,
            looseness=5}
    ]
    \node[state,initial] (q1) {$q_i^1$ \\ -------- \\ A}; 
    \node[state] (q2) [right=of q1] {$q_i^2$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
    \node[state] (q3) [right=of q2] {$q_i^3$ \\ -------- \\ B}; 
    \draw[->] (q1) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q1);
    \draw[->] (q1) edge node [above] {D} (q2);
    \draw[->] (q2) edge node [above] {D} (q3);
    \draw[->] (q3) to[loop above] node [above] {\texttt{C}} (q3);
    \draw[->] (q3) .. controls +(140:2.5) and +(40:2.5) .. (q1)
        node[pos=0.12,below]{D}
        node[pos=0.8,above]{\scriptsize $2/3$}
        node[pos=0.25](temp){};
    \draw[->] (temp.center) .. controls +(15:1) and +(120:1) .. (q3) node[pos=0.5,above]{\scriptsize $1/3$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```